# ionic / javascript : text with < a > tag can't be clicked in the HTML

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, hyperlink

I have a text that contain < a > tag but when I display it in the < p > tag it can't be clickable

for example this is the variable of text:

```
var str="Hi <a href='www.google.com'>Google</a> !!!";
```

I used this way to display it but the link still shown as text

```
<p>
   {{str}}
</p>
```

> Output: Hi < a href='www.google.com'>Google< /a> !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just like this:

```
<p [innerHtml]="str"></p>
```